# Is there a better alternative to pip-autoremove?

Tags: python, pip

I've recently been trying to use best practices when installing packages:

1. Only installing global packages when it makes sense.
2. Using virtual environments 99% of the time.
3. Uninstalling packages whenever they are no longer needed.

I find this to work well for me. However, #3 is a pain when uninstalling packages that have a ton of dependencies, like `tensorflow`. In comes, `pip-autoremove` to the rescue.

The issue with `pip-autoremove` is that it removes everything. Here's a scenario:

1. I `pip install matplotlib` because I need to show some plots.
2. I then realize that maybe `seaborn` could fit my needs a little better, so I `pip install seaborn`.
3. I realize that I was wrong and `matplotlib` will actually fit my needs just fine so I `pip-autoremove seaborn`.
4. Uh, oh! That removed `seaborn` **AND** `matplotlib`!
5. Now, I have to `pip install matplotlib` again before I can continue development.

Is there a better solution out there to this specific problem? Or, is this more of me needing to change my philosophy on package management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually recommend using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to handle your virtual environments. Poetry creates a single .venv per project and tracks all your dependencies with two files that can be tracked by git, `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock`.

When you remove with poetry a dependency (seaborn) that also depends on another installed dependency (matplotlib), poetry will remove all the extra dependencies that seaborn has installed and rollback the matplotlib dependencies to their previously installed version.

Comment: I've actually used Poetry before, but I always add it later on in development, after I've worked out what packages I do/don't need. In that, I've never been in this situation before, and I didn't realize it managed package removals in this manner. Thanks!

Comment: There are other tools, direct concurrent of Poetry, most notably [*Hatch*](https://pypi.org/project/hatch/) and [*PDM*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/). Then with a different scope, but that would still cover your original needs, I can think of [*Pipenv*](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) and [*pip-tools*](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/). I try to cove this here: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging_tools_comparisons.html